# How to Find Max Value for each criteria in a Table View

Tags: mysql, sql, fuzzy

I have database name "spkfu" and it has four table for my final project.

first table is "Alternative"

| id_alternative | name |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Alex |
| 2 | Felix |

second table is "Criteria"
This table contains the weight of the criteria that have been determined by the expert

| id_criteria | name_criteria | weight_value1 | weight_value2 | weight_value3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Job | 0.40 | 0.60 | 0.80 |
| 2 | School | 0.75 | 0.85 | 0.95 |
| 3 | Income | 0.50 | 0.75 | 1.00 |

third table is "Intervals"
this table has the value of each criterion

| id_interval | id_criteria | value_criteria | value_interval | fuzzy_number1 | fuzzy_number2 | fuzzy_number3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | low | 0.00 | 0.25 | 0.50 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | med | 0.25 | 0.50 | 0.75 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | high | 0.50 | 0.75 | 1.00 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | low | 0.00 | 0.25 | 0.50 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | med | 0.25 | 0.50 | 0.75 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | high | 0.50 | 0.75 | 1.00 |
| 7 | 3 | 1 | low | 0.00 | 0.25 | 0.50 |
| 8 | 3 | 2 | med | 0.25 | 0.50 | 0.75 |
| 9 | 3 | 3 | high | 0.50 | 0.75 | 1.00 |

fourth table is "Technical Aspect"
This table has the value of each alternative and the criteria that have been filled in

| id_tehnical_aspect | id_alternative | id_criteria | value_criteria |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 | 3 |
| 5 | 2 | 2 | 2 |
| 6 | 2 | 3 | 1 |

My Table view "v_datanilaikriteria" this table is the full version of the assessment aspect table

| id_alternative | id_criteria | value_criteria | fuzzy_number1 | fuzzy_number2 | fuzzy_number3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 | 0.00 | 0.25 | 0.50 |
| 1 | 2 | 1 | 0.00 | 0.25 | 0.50 |
| 1 | 3 | 3 | 0.50 | 0.75 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 1 | 3 | 0.50 | 0.75 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 2 | 2 | 0.25 | 0.50 | 0.75 |
| 2 | 3 | 1 | 0.00 | 0.25 | 0.50 |

with this code on view table

```
select `spkfu`.`alternative`.`id_alternative` AS `id_alternative`,`spkfu`.`criteria`.`id_criteria`     
AS `id_criteria`,`spkfu`.`technical_aspect`.`value_criteria`
AS `value_criteria`,`spkfu`.`intervals`.`fuzzy_number1` 
AS `fuzzy_number1`,`spkfu`.`intervals`.`fuzzy_number2` 
AS `fuzzy_number2`,`spkfu`.`intervals`.`fuzzy_number3` 
AS `fuzzy_number3` from (((`spkfu`.`technical_aspect` join `spkfu`.`alternative` on(`spkfu`.`alternative`.`id_alternative` = `spkfu`.`tehcnical_aspect`.`id_alternative`))
join `spkfu`.`criteria` on(`spkfu`.`criteria`.`id_criteria` = `spkfu`.`tehcnical_aspect`.`id_criteria`))
join `spkfu`.`intervals` on(`spkfu`.`intervals`.`id_criteria` = `spkfu`.`technical_aspect`.`id_criteria` and `spkfu`.`intervals`.`value_criteria` = `spkfu`.`technical_aspect`.`value_criteria`))
```

**how do I want to find the maximum value (fuzzy_number3) for each criterion from the many alternatives, I need a result like this :**

| id_kriteria | max_number |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 1.00 |
| 2 | 0.75 |
| 3 | 1.00 |

I've tried to find the maximum value but can only 1 criteria per table
with this code

```
select max(`spkfu`.`intervals`.`fuzzy_number3`) AS `max_k1`,`spkfu`.`criteria`.`id_criteria` AS 
`id_criteria` from (((`spkfu`.`technical_aspect` join `spkfu`.`alternative` 
on(`spkfu`.`alternative`.`id_alternative` = `spkfu`.`technical_aspect`.`id_alternative`)) join 
`spkfu`.`criteria` on(`spkfu`.`criteria`.`id_criteria` = `spkfu`.`technical_aspect`.`id_criteria`)) 
join `spkfu`.`intervals` on(`spkfu`.`intervals`.`id_criteria` = 
`spkfu`.`technical_aspect`.`id_criteria` and `spkfu`.`intervals`.`value_criteria` = 
`spkfu`.`technical_aspect`.`value_criteria`)) where `spkfu`.`criteria`.`id_criteria` = '1'
```

the result

| max_k1 | id_criteria |
| --- | --- |
| 1.00 | 1 |

Comment: USE GROUP BY with id criteria

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the where condition and `group by` `id.criteria`

```
    select max(`intervals`.`fuzzy_number3`) AS `max_k1`,
           `criteria`.`id_criteria` AS `id_criteria` 
    from (((`technical_aspect` 
         join `alternative` on(`alternative`.`id_alternative` = `technical_aspect`.`id_alternative`)) 
         join `criteria` on (`criteria`.`id_criteria` = `technical_aspect`.`id_criteria`)) 
         join `intervals` on (`intervals`.`id_criteria` = 
    `technical_aspect`.`id_criteria` and `intervals`.`value_criteria` = 
    `technical_aspect`.`value_criteria`))  
   group by id_criteria;
```

Demo: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/7yUJcuMJPncBBnrExKbzYz/36

[image]